# Is it correct to say "she might hit her elbows on your face" or "she might hit you on the face with her elbows"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-request, phrase-choice

My wife is exercising while my child is running around close to her.

Is it correct for me to say "**stay away from her or else she might hit her elbows on your face**" or "**stay away from her or else she might hit you on the face with her elbows**"?

When we say "**she might hit you on the face**", "**hit**” here implies “**hit on purpose**” but mom didn’t intend to do that.

but when we say “**I hit my knee on the table**” means I did it by accident not on purpose.

So, the question is whether I can say “**she might hit her elbows on your face**”.

Comment: No, it is not idiomatic at all. It should be: **her elbows might hit your face or hit you in the face**. "I hit my elbow on something" requires the something to be **solid**: the floor, the door, the diving board,. Not soft tissue.

Comment: Why, I wonder, might the kid get hurt by his exercising mom's elbow only? There're other moving parts of her body that may make a hurtful for the child, and for the mother as well, contact of any part of her body with that of the kid. Why not just say, "you may get hurt"or "she may accidentally hit (and hurt) you?

Comment: I would just say 'she might elbow you in the face".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, but that could change the meaning....

Comment: @Lambie - could or would?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Could, in fact. :)

Comment: @Lambie - I think your 'her elbows could hit your face' is better - no implication of intention.

Comment: I think the important bit should go first, and that's getting hit in the face. Compare "You might bang your head on the door frame" (WATCH YOUR HEAD!), and "You might damage the door frame if you try and push that wardrobe through." (WATCH THE DOOR FRAME!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither option is really incorrect from a grammar standpoint but a native speaker would not use either of them. We don't say that someone "hits *on* someone's face." *On* is used more when your *face* (or other part of your body) hits some inanimate object, like "I smacked my face on the open cabinet door" or in your example "I hit my knee on the table."

Instead we use "with" to indicate the object used to hit your face:

> She might hit your face **with her elbows**.

Comment: Why not "She might hit you in the face"?

Comment: That's also possible, but you would still use "... *with* her elbows."

Comment: "hit her elbows on your face" is not idiomatic. hit elbows on something requires a solid object.

Comment: I heard someone tell me it is wrong to say "**I hit his face**" but "**I hit him in the face**"

Comment: @Tom Yes, it may be wrong but it is not grammatically wrong.

Comment: I don't think you can hit someone's face with your elbows unless the situation is very unusual. She was swinging on the swing sideways and hit her mother with her elbow.

Comment: @Lambie - when I was young, if a man acted inappropriately towards a woman she might **slap his face**. Also it was done to people who were 'having hysterics' or acting in an automatic way following a shock.